# Why my Text to Speech setup does not initialize successfully?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

For some reason, stautus in the onInit method will never be TextToSpeech.SUCCESS. Why?

```
package me.ruben.learningproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements    TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    TextToSpeech tts;
    EditText inputText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status){
        if(status != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing text to speech!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.speakBtn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                speak();
            }
        });
    }

    void speak(){
        tts.speak(inputText.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

It doesn't even work after a reboot and I don't get any compilation errors in Android Studio.

Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the implementation of `stopSelf()` before `speak()` method.

Comment: Thanks! But how would I have to implement that? Can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 0):

To trigger it, add a button in the onCreate which can run your method.

```
btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speak();
            }

        });
```

and a small change in your existing method, speak():

```
private void speak() {

 String text = inputText.getText().toString();
     tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Init()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(status != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){

                         Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing text to speech!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         return;
                    }
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.speakBtn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()    {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                                speak();
                           }
                      });
                }
            }).start();


}
```

Running that on a different thread may help ..!!